# examples of implementation of NAT traversal techniques in (android ?) p2p applications

Tags: android, p2p, traversal, nat

I am currently working on an Android peer-to-peer application.
Of course, we soon realized that one of the most difficult tasks is to figure out how to traverse NATs to allow 2 devices (or more) to communicate with each other over the internet, regardless of the distance between them.

I have been doing some research, read about STUN(T), ICE, TURN and found some implementations including Ice4j, JStun,[IcedJava](http://java.net/projects/siptools/pages/IcedJava),[NUTSS](http://nutss.gforge.cis.cornell.edu/stunt.php)...

Would you know about examples of practical use of at least one of these techniques, possibly in existing (android or other) peer to peer applications ?
The most useful for us would be the ones that don't need the app to use any additional relay server.

Other suggestions are welcome as well!

Thanks a lot in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Just to know a device Ip and Port by NAT, other device connect to the one. 
IcedJava implementation RFC5389, JStun implementation RFC3489.

Answer (score -1):

AFAIK It is impossible to avoid a relay server of some sort with Android applications: the IPs allocated to the mobile devices by the telcos are not fixed and not publicly accessible: there is no way you can establish a direct connection to a mobile device.